# How to apply css rules to a link which is inside multiple divs?

Tags: html, css

In my html code I want to create a link to a **Ratings** page :

```html
<div class = "products">
    <div class = "container">
        <div class = "product-items">
            <div class = "product">
                <div class = "product-info">    
                    <div class = "product-info-top">
                        <a href="../ratings/ratings.html"><h2 class = "sm-title">Ratings</h2></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css code :

```css
.product{
    margin: 2rem;
    position: relative;
}

.container{
    width: 88vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.product-info{
    background: rgb(63, 34, 34);
    padding: 2rem;
}

.product-info-top{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.sm-title{
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

But when i tried changing the link appearance, as well as change its color when visited etc, it didnt affect the link :

```css
a{
   text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited{
   color: #somehexvalue;
}
```

I also tried applying a class to this link tag but again did not work.

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/ory96tw8/7/
Make sure you replace #somehexvalue with an actual hex value

Comment: yeah, there is a lot more code with external css etc. I just posted the part with the link.
Since im a beginner, im guessing im missing something that stands out.

Comment: @BernardBorg that would be a poor recommendation. `!important` should not be used. It does not fix an issue you have, it just hides the issue and causes other issues in return. Any decent developer will look into the specificity weight and fix the issue on that level instead. The only real reason to use it is to overwrite templates in CMS where you have limited access to edit the code.

Comment: That is a fair point @tacoshy but without any further styles provided we can't really help further. I gave him a solution he could use if all else fails. Maybe I should've mentioned this in my earlier comment.

Comment: Time to learn about **Developer Tools**. All the browsers have them. Right click on the link and select "Inspect" this will show you the styles applied to the element , including indicating styles that have been over-ridden. Then learn about CSS Specificity. Which explains why `div a {some style}` over rides `a {some style}`

Comment: Edit your question to put your code into a Stack Snippet, so we can run it and see for ourselves.

Comment: Have you shown us all the relevant CSS or are you using something else as well, e.g. bootstrap? If so you may find it is placing styles in style attributes.

Comment: Thank you guys, i resolved the issue.
Turns out i needed to place the link inside a div element with an existing class i mistakenly did not mention to you.
Still does not make sense why this would work and not when i tried creating my own class, but issue got solved.
Thanks again for the tips and comments:)